# Blow-ups followed by contractions

Tags: algebraic-geometry, surfaces, minimal-surfaces, birational-geometry

Let $S$ be a **minimal**, non-singular complex projective surface. $\widehat S$ is the surface obtained by $r$ blow-ups of $S$ at the points $x_1,\ldots,x_r\in S$. Clearly $\widehat S$ contains exactly $r$ (-1)-curves and now if we contract all these curves we obtain another minimal surface $X$ such that $K^2_X=K^2_S$. Under this hypothesis can we conclude that $S$ and $X$ are isomorphic?

I suppose that the answer is **no**, because in this way I simply find two minimal models of $\widehat S$.

What do you think?

Comment: Well, except for Kodaira dimension $0$, minimal surfaces are unique within birational equivalence classes, and since $S$ and $\widehat{S}$ are birational..

Comment: Do you mean "...except for Kodaira dimension $-\infty$" right? Unfortunately my case of study is a ruled surface.

Comment: I did mean $-\infty$. :) Yeah, I'll have to think more about that then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The statement

> Clearly $\widehat S$ contains exactly $r$ (-1)-curves

is false. For example, blow up $\mathbf P^2$ in 2 points. Then the exceptional curves are (-1)-curves, but there is *another* (-1)-curve on this surface: namely the proper transform of the line that went through the two points. If we contract just that last (-1)-curve, we get the minimal surface $\mathbf P^1 \times \mathbf P^1 \neq \mathbf P^2.$ This is the point about non-uniqueness of minimal models for Kodaira dimension $-\infty$: blowing up can create **more** (-1)-curves than just the exceptional curves.

On the other hand, if the (-1)-curves you contract are exactly the exceptional curves of the blowups, then **yes**, certainly $S$ and $X$ will be isomorphic: contracting the curves is just undoing what you did when you blew up the points.

Comment: Fantastic answer! I guess I never realized that, as you said, the issue for $\kappa(X)=-\infty$ is precisely the ability to introduce more $(-1)$-curves.

Comment: @AlexYoucis: thanks! For more fun, trying blowing up 9 points in $\mathbf P^2$, and see how many $(-1)$-curves you get...

Comment: Hmm, is there a nice way of seeing this? Besides writing down the Chow ring of the blow up (using the formula) is there an easy way of deducing the number of $(-1)$-curves? Thanks!

Comment: @AlexYoucis: no, I don't think there's a very easy way. There's an obvious basis for $Pic(X)$, and writing classes in that basis turns the problem into a sort of Diophantine problem in 10 variables. These comments aren't the place for details; instead you could read this beautiful paper of Totaro: http://www.math.ucla.edu/~totaro/papers/public_html/hilbert.pdf

Comment: Thanks :) I'll take a look!